# GTK+ Drag File Onto GUI

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am working on an application in GTK+ and C, and am wondering if there is a way to support dragging files onto the GUI (across File Explorers and Desktop Environments). I have been able to achieve dragging text (through `gtk_drag_dest_set` and `g_signal_connect`) but dragging files onto the GUI has no effect. I am wondering if this is something that varies by Distro and Desktop Environment or if there is a good way to do this universally. My code for dropping text is [here](https://pastebin.com/vd17ABHJ) and the Makefile [here](https://pastebin.com/Pt8pNyrj).

Surely there is a way to do this? I am able to drag files into apps like Firefox, Sublime Text, and VS Code...

EDIT (Clarification): I am using XFCE, but I would like to find a solution which supports other Desktops like Gnome and KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your target entries to this:

```
static GtkTargetEntry targetentries[] =
{
      { "STRING",        0, TARGET_STRING },
      { "text/plain",    0, TARGET_STRING },
      { "text/uri-list", 0, TARGET_URL },
};
```

You do not have the item (`text/uri-list`) that tells GTK+: "I want you to listen for files that are being dragged in.
The place I found this was here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/DnD

I found this page while doing research for a GUI GTK+ fronted to the GNU Coreutils `shred`.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow though this gives me an [error](https://pastebin.com/3gDhybyW). Maybe it is an issue with my Makefile or includes?

Comment: Looking into it more, it seems that this syntax is GTK+ 2 specific. I am working on finding the equivalent for GTK+ 3.

Comment: In that case check the GTK3 reference manual. You can get it by installing `devhelp` program

Comment: I made a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062089/how-do-i-do-drag-and-drop-in-gtk3) for that.